# linux nginx dotnet core app signalr not working over ssl

Tags: linux, nginx, .net-core, websocket, signalr

This was working when testing out the app. When i switched the DNS over to the server and then added SSL cert, signalR stopped working (my chat). I presume it's to do with the proxy now redirecting to port 443. The rest of the website works, just not its' chat functionality.

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://www.my-website.com/chatHub?id=qDsSrV-APYXpnyk_EfsrXw. signalr.min.js:16:110126
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled.
```

and the config in nginx:

```
server {
    server_name www.my-website.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }

}
server {
    if ($host = www.my-website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen        80;
    server_name www.my-website.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Any help on getting signalR working again would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you share your hub backend implementation ?
I. tried you nginx configuration and it seems to work, maybe try to add
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out that when Certbot edited the config, it added an extra unncessary `}`. and that's all that was breaking it. The config was broken and was serving a cached state. So i was viewing the website via https:// but was trying to make a websocket connection on port 80, and was failing because it was unsecure.